# Find $f$, such that $e^{f'(x)}+f(x)=e^{-x^2}+e^{-2xe^{-x^2}},\ \forall x\in\mathbb{R}$

Tags: calculus, functions

I have constructed a great exercise but now I don't know how to solve it without using sequences. My original thought was kind of "EVT in an open interval" with reductio ad absurdum. Can you help me solve it?

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function, such
>   that $e^{f'(x)}+f(x)=e^{-x^2}+e^{-2xe^{-x^2}},\ \forall x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\lim_\limits{x\to +\infty}{f(x)}=\lim_\limits{x\to -\infty}{f(x)}=0$. Find $f$.

Comment: Any help here???

Answer (score 1):

Well, simply by inspection:
$$e^{\color{red}{f'(x)}}+\color{blue}{f(x)}=\color{blue}{e^{-x^2}}+e^{\color{red}{-2xe^{-x^2}}}$$

Gives you $\color{blue}{f(x)=e^{-x^2}}$...

This also satisfies:
$$\lim_{x \to +\infty} e^{-x^2} = \lim_{x \to -\infty} e^{-x^2} = 0$$

But I assume you're looking for a more general approach?

Comment: Obviuos but, still, nice answer. How would you show whether that $f$ is unique or just a particular case of a more general answer?

Comment: For the moment, I don't (know)... But that wasn't asked either :o).

Comment: Well, I know what is $f$, since I constructed the exercise. However, I was looking for an austere proof.

Comment: "My original thought was kind of "EVT in an open interval" with reductio ad absurdum." as I said before.

Comment: It was asked to find each and every function(s) that satisfies the given data with a rigorous proof.

Comment: I must admit I didn't read your question carefully enough, I only noticed that you made the exercise yourself after I had started writing this answer. I (still) couldn't find the part in the question where it is asked to find *all functions* that satisfy this equation, but now I understand that this is what you meant/want. Perhaps someone else will be able to help.